# Referencing operands/parameters in GNU assembler macros

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, macros, gnu-assembler

I am currently trying to understand the concept of **macros in the assembly language**, specifically in GNU assembler, AT&T syntax for IA-32 (x86). The slides from my university say the following:

```
# How to define a macro:
.macro write string
    movl string, %esi
    call printstr
.endm

# How to use a macro:
write aString
```

However, this doesn't work for me. I am using **gcc** to compile my code.

```
.data
    msg:    .string "The result is %d.\n"

.text
.global main

.macro add_3 n
    movl n, %eax
    addl $3, %eax
.endm

main:
    add_3 $39
    pushl %eax
    pushl $msg
    call printf
    popl %eax
    popl %eax
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error:

```
undefined reference to `n'
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try prepending the argument names with a backslash when using them inside the macro. I.e. `movl \n, %eax`

Comment: This question has been hanging open, so I am answering it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To reference arguments inside the macro, prepend the name with a backslash.
For example:

```
.macro  add_3  n
    movl \n + 3, %eax
.endm
```

GAS manual: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Macro.html